# How does Scrapy avoid re-downloading media that was downloaded recently?

Tags: python, scrapy

According to https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html, both Scrapy's Files Pipeline and Images Pipeline "avoid re-downloading media that was downloaded recently".

I have a spider which I'm running using a [job directory](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#job-directory) (`JOBDIR`) in order to pause and resume crawls. Initially I was scraping items without downloading files; later on, I added a Files Pipeline. However, I forgot to delete the `JOBDIR` before re-running the spider 'for real' with the Pipeline.

What I'm afraid of is that the `requests.seen` file in the `JOBDIR` will contain fingerprints of items which have been scraped, but of which there is no scraped file (because the pipeline was not yet in place when they were scraped). What I'm considering doing is to remove the `JOBDIR` and start scraping again from a clean slate.

My question is: will this work without downloading all the files again? Or does the `FilesPipeline` rely on the `JOBDIR` to skip files that have already been downloaded recently? (My `FILES_SOURCE` is a S3 bucket by the way).

Comment: Maybe you can try to set `dont_filter=True` in you `scrapy.Request`

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy calculates file name (usually it's base64 from url for image) and if file exists in folder, scrapy won't try to download it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to re download it forcefully, you can set IMAGES_EXPIRE or FILES_EXPIRE to 0 in the settings file.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question of OP. He was asking how does scrapy avoid re-downloading, not how to avoid this mechanism. This might be an interesting comment but is not an answer.