# Scrapy FilesPipeline avoid re-downloading files (Google Cloud Storage) on different crawl runs

Tags: python, scrapy, google-cloud-storage

I know there is allready a question regarding this here ([How to avoid re-downloading media to S3 in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824013/how-to-avoid-re-downloading-media-to-s3-in-scrapy)) but I do not have my answer yet

I have designed a spider with a FilesPipeline to get pdf files from several websites.

I understand that the `FilesPipeline` class is using the `GCSFilesStore` and the function `media_to_download` to compare the blob `last_modified` attribute date to the current time with respect to an expiration duration in days (`EXPIRES` initially equals 90) 
The point is that I want to be able to launch my spider from time to time and to only download new documents

However when I run my spider a second time, **it does re-download all the files again**

I have tried to increase the `EXPIRES` parameter but it did not seem to cut it.

Any help appreciated thanks !

**UPDATE :**

I think this is a bug from scrapy. I filed a [bug report on github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4346) where I explain how to reproduce this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this may be due to some permissions configuration with the bucket. Here is github user @michalp123's answer :

> Blockquote
>   I cannot reproduce this bug. @lblanche, are you sure you set up permissions for the bucket correctly? The very first time I've tried reproducing it I got a setup where the service account I used had write permissions, but for some reason calling get_blob on the bucket raised a 403, which caused stat_file method in GCSFilesStore to fail, and that caused the file to be downloaded every time. After fixing the permissions everything worked as it should. If that's the case here, I think it would be a good idea to check permissions in GCSFilesStore's **init** and display a warning if it's impossible to get file's metadata from the bucket.

The same user merged a fix that adds a warning at `GCSFilesStore` init if the access to the metadata is not allowed.